# Which badges are awarded only once?

Tags: discussion, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do “badges” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work)

In SO, which badges are awarded only once?

Comment: The FAQ entry is nice, but it doesn't actually contain the answer to this question. (Unless you count the link to the [list of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions), but then this question should have been closed as a dupe of that one directly.)

Answer (score 6):

The badges that can be awarded multiple times say so in the description on their individual badge pages:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/19/enlightened

> First answer was accepted with at least 10 up votes. **This badge can be awarded multiple times.**

Comment: They should say that on the badges page, too…

Answer (score 0):

You can see information on [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions).

There you can see which badges are awarded once and which badges awarded multiple times.