# Complete list of badges that can be earned on StackOverflow?

Tags: support, badges

Is there a page somewhere that lists all the badges that are available on StackOverflow (and what is required to earn them)?

I was thinking someone must have asked this question before, but my searches came up empty.

Comment: That's 'cause it's linked to on every page... http://stackoverflow.com/badges

See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work-in-stackoverflow

Comment: Well don't I look silly :(

Answer (score 1):

Except the Generalist badge (throws `NotImplementedException`) and the Beta badge (no longer relevant), all badges on the https://stackoverflow.com/badges page can still be earned, along with specialized badges for every tag.

Comment: Might be nice if they could take Beta 'off' the badges page, or possibly on the bottom in a section called 'Previous Badges'.

Comment: Why? Those who already have the badge have lifetime support -- for testing the system with a lot of subjective and poll "questions" and answers.

Comment: *"for testing the system with a lot of subjective and poll "questions" and answers"* Hey now! Some of us didn't participate in those (well, not much anyway) and argued against their existence. Is was the first big schism around here. The much feared and hated Community Wiki police are the resulting compromise.

Comment: @dmckee: you guys are legends and truly deserve your Beta badge. If the community is not degenerated into Yahoo answers, it's totally Because of You! You set the social foundations of the community quite well.

Comment: That sounds all together too heroic and intentional: we somehow, not quite knowing what we did, groped and muddled our way into something that mostly works...