# Where is my 'good question' badge? :)

Tags: support, badges

I didn't get badge for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502354/what-is-pattern-matching-in-functional-languages) which was upvoted 10th time about an hour ago.

My suggestions:

1) <strike>Slowpoke is so slow</strike> I'll get it a bit later due to some service delays.

2) it's a bug, which can be explained: some time ago I earned similar badge for the question which was later closed and deleted (or merged with something but I wasn't notified about it - one day it just disappeared). So till this moment I had 3 questions with 10+ votes and 4 'nice-question' badges. At the moment there are 4 appropriate questions and 4 badges.

Comment: It's answer 2 (sort of). If a post that earned you a badge is deleted you have one "extra" badge and won't earn another one until you've "caught up"

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: when I think about how would I implement it I understand that it's very hard problem with unclear logic. But now it looks like a bug.

Comment: @voyager: what should we find there?

Comment: *The site admin has stated multiple times that, by design, badges cannot be lost or revoked.* (...) *If the criteria for the badge no longer exists, such as if the post it was based on is deleted. When badges are awarded, the system checks to see how many you're supposed to have, and only awards new badges when the number of badges you're supposed to have is greater than the number of badges you have.*

Comment: *As an example, suppose one of your answers received 10 up-votes, which caused you to earn the Nice Answer badge. After you have the badge, that same answer is down-voted to a score under 10. The next time you have an answer that gets 10 up-votes, you will not earn an additional Nice Answer badge because the system sees that you already have the number of Nice Answer badges that you should have, and doesn't award the additional badge.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some badges aren't awarded real-time, but rather calculated from a batch script. If you're eligible for it, you'll probably get it shortly after 00:00 UTC.

However, if you were previously awarded this badge for a post that is no longer eligible (because a user was deleted, a vote was reversed or the question itself was deleted) then you have a "credit" of one badge, so the next time you earn one for real it will just pay back this credit.

Comment: Hah beat by 25 seconds *deletes own answer*

Comment: @Ether, I know you've answered a question like this very recently but I couldn't find the link.

Comment: @rlb: yeah, everything all kind of mushes together after a while :)

Comment: +1 - This probably explains the reason why I searched meta and found this Q&A.

Answer (score 0):

You suggestion #2 is how it works. When you fulfill the criteria for a new badge the script checks how many badges you already have and you only get a new one if you don't already have "enough" of them.

This is not a bug, but by-design.