# Can the Electorate badge be revoked?

Tags: discussion, badges, stack-exchange, electorate-badge, revoked-badges

For the sake of a simple example, say you vote for exactly 601 questions and 1800 answers.  Congrats, you've earned Electorate.  But what if your next ten votes are all for answers?  Then you'd be at 601:1810, which would put you at < 25% questions.  Would the badge be taken away?

I know that the general rule is that badges never go away, but the [badge FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work) does state that one of the two exceptions to the rule is when "the criteria for the badge no longer exist."

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No.

I got the electorate badge because I stopped voting on answers, once I got it, I resume voting on answers (and in fact, I voted more on answers than on questions) losing the eligibility ratio and I did *not* lose the badge.

Answer (score 3):

The only time a badge has been removed, that wasn't due to a deletion. Was when the requirements to achieve the Beta badge was changed. So I doubt that anyone will receive this badge only to lose it later.