# Is it possible to lose the Electorate badge?

Tags: support, electorate-badge

The criteria for the [Electorate](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/155/electorate) badge is:

> Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on
>   questions.

Now assume I vote on the required 600 questions with a ratio > 0.25 and I get the Electorate badge. Down the line (assuming I go on an **answer** voting spree), if my ratio drops back to below 0.25, would I effectively lose the badge? And presumably gain it back after I bring my ratio > 0.25?

I know [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45524/can-the-electorate-badge-be-revoked) answer sort of addressed that but I'm looking for more of an *official* answer on how that works, as opposed to *no that didn't happen to me*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can the Electorate badge be revoked?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45524/can-the-electorate-badge-be-revoked)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to lose badges?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58053/is-it-possible-to-lose-badges)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, you will never lose any non-tag badge, this is by design.

Comment: (except special cases, but this isn't one of them)

Comment: But you can lose tag badges, right?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi yes http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/87514/166936

Comment: Yup, special case