# Why are these badges not on badges list while they exist?

Tags: support, badges

I realized some new badges on Superuser.com:

- [windows](https://superuser.com/badges/52/windows)
- [windows-xp](https://superuser.com/badges/51/windows-xp)
- [windows-7](https://superuser.com/badges/48/windows-7)
- [windows](https://superuser.com/badges/41/windows)
- [linux](https://superuser.com/badges/50/linux)

Why are these badges not on [badges](https://superuser.com/badges) page while they exist and are in use?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work/17854#17854

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the badges page, there is a tab on the right which says "tags". Click it to see [all of the tag-based badges](https://superuser.com/badges?tab=tags). Example link is for Superuser specifically.