# Why do some users earn the specialist badge with less than 400 votes?

Tags: support, badges, specialist-badge

The [specialist silver badge](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/specialist-badge-implemented/)  should be awarded by having 400+ upvotes in a tag.

Some users already have this badge with [less than 250 votes](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/42/java) in this tag?

Does the number of accepted answers or anything else influence the calculation?

Comment: Related: [How do badges work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/)

Comment: http://cloudexchange.cloudapp.net/stackoverflow/q/2365

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confusing "number of answers" with "number of votes".

Each answer can have more than one vote.

But remember that the tag badges ignore community wiki questions and answers.

Comment: thanks I've obviously misinterpreted the numbers