# Does a bounty reduce reputation counting towards a tag-based badge?

Tags: support, reputation, badges, bounties, specialist-badge

Does offering a bounty have any negative effect on reputation that's counting towards a tag-based badge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tag-badges are earned through upvotes, not reputation gained.

Search for "How do I get the tag specialist badges?" on [*How do “badges” work?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/)