# Why are badges kept, even if pertinent action is reversed?

Tags: discussion, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do “badges” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work)

So earlier today I down voted an answer.... then I read it again, and I realized I has misunderstood something, so I cancelled my down vote... Yet, [I still have the first down vote badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/7/critic?user_id=148317) even though [I have no down votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/148317/peter-ajtai).

This also works with some other badges, like filling out all you profile info.... You can fill out all your info, get your badge, then delete your info.

I guess I can see plus and minuses for this. So my question is, **is this a feature or a bug?**

Comment: You're 5 days too early for the weekly [Is This a Feature Or A Bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58206/start-a-bounty-shows-for-accepted-answer-question-closed) episode.

Comment: ..Because the "badge recalc" function has not yet been written.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design, see the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work):

> The site admin has stated multiple times that, by design, badges cannot be lost or revoked, unless the badge was obtained by cheating.

Comment: Is it because it is hard for SO to revoke badges due to technical reasons that you have no choice but to keep the badges?

Comment: Badges, especially the bronze and silver ones, are incentives for doing the "right" thing by participating in voting, asking, and answering.  The fact that you placed a vote means you are participating, even if you later changed your mind, and so you should still be rewarded.

Comment: I understand, but filling out your profile completely, then deleting it, almost seems like cheating... I'm really not sure whether it is or not.

Comment: @Peter Ajtai: I wouldn't consider it cheating, you *did* fill out your profile *at one point*, that's what the badge is for, *that* action, regardless of any future actions. The same goes for the downvote, *at the time it was awarded* you met the criteria.  Yes you reversed the vote, but you *did cast a downvote*, and that's what you got a badge for.

Answer (score 1):

When you no longer qualify for a badge, you will stop "gaining" badge until the number you deserve matches the number you have. So you can't get *extra* badges. Every badge that you have a is a badge that you earned *at some point*.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, for some badges which you can earn *multiple* times, the calculation is done at regular intervals and compared against your current number.  So while you can't *lose* one of them, you'll only reflect a increase if you still qualify for the earlier badges.