# What are the coins next to one's name?

Tags: discussion

I didn't see this in the FAQ so I'm posting it here.  I frequently see gold/copper/silver coins next to someone's name, what are these?  Oh... are they achievements?  Like you've received 2 silver achievements

Comment: You are correct.  Here we call them badges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Badges. [See this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges).

Answer (score 0):

They're called badges. You can read about them in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work) and see the full details of each badge [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions).