# Is a badge retracted if the vote count falls below the threshold?

Tags: support, badges, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do “badges” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work)

For badges that are tied to a specific vote count (for example, a badges for 50 up votes on a particular reply) once the badge is awarded, if the reply is then voted down below the threshold, is the badge retracted or removed?

Answer (score 6):

No, you get to keep it.

However, the next time you have a qualifying post for the same badge, if the first post hasn't gone over the threshold again, you will not receive an *additional* badge of the same type because it "made up" for the one you "don't have" -- if that makes sense.

The only other way a non-tag badge will be revoked is if a dev made a mistake and they need to do a manual recalculation of badges.

Answer (score 5):

No, badges are not removed except in very special circumstances (e.g. if badges are awarded erroneously by some new script).