# Badges vs "number you are supposed to have"

Tags: discussion, support, badges

I first used the title "can a badge be lost" and followed most of the links that look relevant, but they are still not clear or specific enough.

The prior questions dealt with badges in the same category, more precisely I believe the "can be awarded multiple times" badges.

The [FAQ has this to say](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work/17854#17854)

My question is, if one earns `Nice Question` and the question was then downvoted back to 9, I understand that the badge is not taken off. If you get another `Nice Question`, you can mentally assume that the badge has been "reassigned" to that question.  What if, instead of getting another `Nice Question`, you are eligible for an `Enlightened` bad instead?  Do you get it?

What role do deleted questions play in this equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [link you cite](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work/17854#17854) (emphasis mine):

> However, if the criteria for a badge no longer exist — e.g. the post it was awarded for is deleted — the next award **of that badge** is negated. When badges are awarded, the system checks to see how many you're supposed to have, and only awards new badges when the number of badges you're supposed to have is greater than the number of badges you have.

So if your post if voted down to 9 and no longer qualifies, the next time a question is voted up enough to qualify for the `Nice Question` badge (whether it is the same question voted back to 10 or a different one), you will *not* be awarded a new one.

The `Nice Question` badge count has nothing to do with the `Enlightened` badge count; the check for that badge is treated separately since it is a different badge.

Comment: To me, it is ambiguous whether it refers to "that class" (bronze/silver/gold) or "that name".

Comment: @cyberkiwi - it treats each badge separately. If you no longer qualify for a "Nice Answer" badge it doesn't stop you receiving a "Nice Question" badge.