# In Stackoverflow I noticed badges, What do they mean?

Tags: support, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do “badges” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work)

In Stackoverflow I noticed badges, What do they mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Please read....

https://stackoverflow.com/badges