# Does the generalist badge require 15 score total, or 15 score per tag?

Tags: support, badges, generalist-badge

The description says, we can earn it by:

> Provided non-wiki answers of 15 total score in 20 of top 40 tags

Does it mean a 15 score in each of the tags, or in cumulation?

Say 10 in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) and 5 in [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c) and I am done, or 15 in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), 15 in [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c) and others...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's definitely not 15 total score across all tags.

According to the [What are the badges I can earn on each site, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/143601), it requires a cumulative answer score (all upvotes minus all downvotes)  > 15 *per tag* in 20 of the top 40 tags:

> #### Generalist
>
> - silver; awarded once
> - Earn a tag score of 15 on answers belonging to one of the top 40 tags
> - Repeat the above step until any 20 of the top 40 tags are covered

**Also!** Be aware that the Generalist badge requires **the site** to have 200 questions in each of the top 40 tags before *anyone* on the site can get the badge (from https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/generalist-badge-implemented/):

> One thing the badge doesn’t say, is that there must be at least 200 questions in all 40 of the top tags before this badge is awarded to anyone. ... I don’t feel you can accurately measure a generalist until the top tag list settles down.

Comment: Nice; I was trying to find that exact post and failing

Comment: @Michael, it is well hidden, even Google had a hard time finding it. I might edit some FAQ posts to point more answers to it.

Comment: Hmm, no i actually think that link is wrong. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/generalist-badge-implemented/ unless they changed it since. So you need 15 cumulative rep in 20 of the top 40 tags. i.e. a +10, and a +5 in C# would quailify the c# tag to count for you.

Comment: @Zypher: I understand "score" in this case was the same as "total upvotes minus total downvotes", similar to the tag badges.

Comment: @Zypher Yes, I linked to that post too.  I thought that is how it worked, but I don't think the language in the post (unless it's in the comments) really clears it up.  Do you have a further reference for whether it is cumulative or not?

Comment: @renesis in the tag description the word "answers" is plural not singular meaning more than one answer can be used to satisfy the badge not just _one_ answer of +15

Comment: @Zypher - Not that I believe the language in the badge descriptions to be created to a degree that they should be analyzed at this level, but the plural could apply to multiple tags, not multiple answers within every tag.

Comment: @Michael - Have added it to the answer at [How do badges work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work/17854#17854) which is the first post Google finds about badge requirements.

Comment: @Zypher - answer fixed, now that the list has been fixed.  Thanks for bringing it up in chat.

Answer (score 11):

It's 15 score per tag, in any 20 of the top 40 tags. I'm not even sure the other interpretation makes sense; you could end up with 15 score in one tag, and the "20 of top 40 tags" part doesn't do anything