# Generalist Badge Formula

Tags: support, badges, generalist-badge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does the generalist badge require 15 score total, or 15 score per tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85048/does-the-generalist-badge-require-15-score-total-or-15-score-per-tag)

There are a few other questions similar to this, but they are either outdated or not quite the question I'm asking.

**Generalist Badge:** `Provided non-wiki answers of 15 total score in 20 of top 40 tags.`

**Question:** What does `15 total score` mean? Does it mean my answers cover 20 of the top 40, and must total 15 overall tags? Or does it mean I must each 15 points in each of those individual tags?

Note, I understand questions with multiple tags count as answering each tag.

Comment: [This answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85048/does-the-generalist-badge-require-15-score-total-or-15-score-per-tag/85050#85050) and [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/67399#67399) both answer your question even though their questions are not literally exactly duplicates of yours.

Comment: You can use this [data.se query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/34993/) or others like it to see how close you are to getting it as of the last data dump.

Comment: Also your current tag scores can be found on http://stackoverflow.com/users/146610/one-beat-consumer?tab=tags

Comment: @ConradFrix Excellent!

Comment: @one.beat.consumer as an aside I used to think this was a tough badge to get but it [turns out](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/60798/generalist-effort) the average number of answers you need is ~500.

Comment: Tough badge for me ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does it mean my answers cover 20 of the top 40, and must total 15 overall tags?

20 is more than 15.  That interpretation is impossible ... it means that for each of 20+ tags in the top 40 tags, you must have (non-CW) answers totalling 15 score in that tag.

Comment: It is the later then; thank you for clarifying. For the record, 15 points would still be possible across 20 tags in 2 scenarios: (1) you could get 19 0-score answers and 1 15-score answer, and (2) answers count for all tags so assume i have 15 1-score answers, but 5 of those have a second tag. In both these scenarios I would have `15 points across 20 tags`... it seemed a little easy for a silver, but I just wanted to ask.