# Badge/flair for attending a meet up?

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request, meetups

Would it be possible to get some kind of bronze badge or bit of flair to show if someone has attended one of the Stack Overflow meetups?

Comment: `[• Real Person]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While I think it's good to encourage the meetups, I don't think it's appropriate to provide a badge to reward activity that doesn't actively contribute to content creation/moderation/improvement **on this site**.

From the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work/17854#17854):

> Badges are a way of recognizing users who contribute to the website.

There are some current exceptions, like **Quorum** (*One post with score of 2 on meta*) and others like **Announcer** and **Booster** (*Shared a link to a question that was visited by M unique IP addresses in N days*),  but those are also about contributing back to the community as well.

Maybe they could goad some of the location-based checkin providers (foursquare/gowalla/et. al.) to provide a badge though, since those are ones that actually track location checkins.  But given that it's lots of various locations across the globe (some of which haven't even been decided yet), I think that'd be tough to do as well.