# I cheated on the Disciplined badge, how bad is it?

Tags: discussion, badges, gaming-the-system

1. I was looking for badges I didn't have yet, and I saw the Disciplined badge.
2. So I deleted an answer of mine with 3+ votes, and waited.
3. Five minutes later, sweet, a new badge!
4. Then I went to my answer again, and undeleted it.
5. No problem at all, and I keep the badge!

What will happen? Will my badge stay here or not? More generally, what happens when the conditions to get a badge are valid at one time, and then not valid?

Other badge in this case:

- Unsung hero - "*Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total*"

What happens if answers get a vote after getting the badge? Are the badge frequently recalculated?

Comment: `delete from badges where userid = 128662` I'm sorry, what was the question?

Comment: Downvoted to get critic badge.

Comment: Answered in hopes of a future Reversal.

Comment: This question just leaves me wondering why you want the Disciplined badge so much in the first place. It's not exactly as illustrious as, say, Guru or Great Answer.

Comment: Well, SO is about fun, and when I play, I like to have all the achievement :)

Comment: +1 for this one as it made me chuckle. I'd also treat this as an admission of guilt, so well done @Scorpi0

Comment: This question should be A FAQ for `How could I get the Disciplined badge`

Comment: I accidentally the disciplined badge, how bad is it?

Comment: The irony is that you're not earning the Disciplined badge in a disciplined way.

Comment: The irony is that I have earned the 'Nice question' badge for an undisciplined question !

Comment: I wanted to report the same problem, but first did a quick search..  it looks like I'm not the only one.... Well, you know what? I wanted to report a bug and was willing to sacrifice my badge... that surely deserves a disciplined badge, doesn't it?

Comment: I do respect your honesty.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From [How do "badges" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work/17854#17854):

> The site admin has stated multiple
>   times that, by design, badges cannot
>   be lost or revoked, unless they were
>   obtained by cheating.
>
> However, if the criteria for a badge
>   no longer exist — e.g. the post it was
>   awarded for is deleted — the next
>   award of that badge is negated. When
>   badges are awarded, the system checks
>   to see how many you're supposed to
>   have, and only awards new badges when
>   the number of badges you're supposed
>   to have is greater than the number of
>   badges you have.

So unless you cheat, badges are forever. If you *do* cheat and you're caught, say goodbye to your precious bling. Moral: Have fun using the site, but Don't Be That Guy.

Answer (score 16):

Why is this cheating.  You **have** deleted one answer with 3 or more upvotes. There is nothing in the badge descriptions about undeleting.

I agree, its a bit fishy. But it won't get you into any problem (unless people start to downvote you so you can get the peer pressure badge).

If you really don't want to spend the 30 rep for this badge. there are at least two options:

1. delete a answer where the rep is earned when you already past the rep cap.
2. delete a CW answer.

There are probably more valid ways to earn this badge.

Comment: It's "cheating" in the sense that the *purpose* of the badge is to reward folks for being responsible and recognizing that sometimes your own content should be removed in order to help keep the site "clean"

Comment: @Daniel DiPaolo, the problem is not so much his activity is cheating, but that the site was designed with so much flexibility that there is more than one way to achieve the "disciplined" badge (and in fact, it's how I got it myself).

Comment: nothing will happen ,other than your account being deleted from Stack.

Comment: You are encouraging people to focus more on earning badges than on helping others?