# Cheating the system to get Disciplined badge... is that right?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, disciplined-badge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I cheated on the Disciplined badge, how bad is it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95918/i-cheated-on-the-disciplined-badge-how-bad-is-it)
>   [Badges should reward positive behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107628/badges-should-reward-positive-behavior)

I thought if you delete an answer with 3 or more votes, you should lose the "points" and get the `Disciplined` badge, right?
However after I have received the badge I "undeleted" my answer and for my surprise I got the "points" back and also I kept the badge.

I am just wondering if it is correct or it is a system bug.

[Here is my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153546/ruby-on-rails-collection-select-complexity/11155666#11155666).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95918/i-cheated-on-the-disciplined-badge-how-bad-is-it

Comment: AFAIK badges you've obtained are never revoked. So although such "abuse" is not appropriate, I don't think it's a bug either. I would not be surprised though if you somehow might be penalized should your behavior be less than appropriate.

Comment: No, it is not right. Please remain calm while our local Stack Exchange Badge Inquisition Team gets to your house and revokes your `Disciplined` badge, then immediately reinstates it because you made the effort to post this question.

Comment: guys, when I realised that I have loose the points I decided that I prefer the points instead of the badge... I came here to be honest with you guys.... @Frédéric I am happy to have my badge revoked if it is the right procedure :)

Comment: I think this falls into the sort of category where, yes, it's possible to do this... and if someone wants to be that kind of person then that's their problem.  The badge itself means very little.  The fact that you've come here indicates that you have some integrity on the matter.  Congratulations, that integrity earns you a Disciplined badge :)

Comment: I agree it's bit.. silly. The badge, not what you have done. But not all badges make sense to everyone so it's perfectly OK.

Comment: Hey you can delete this question now to earn the badge here on Meta as well! ;-)

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd. I'll give you an upvote, so you can delete the comment, who knows maybe you can get a badge for that. ?!

Comment: @Sha Dow Wiz Ard - if I delete the message I will earn the `Disciplined` badge here, but if I want the `Quorum` badge I should keep it, right? But I haven't received the `Quorum` badge, shall I open a new question or can someone advise about that...

Comment: I got it now... thanks

Comment: @gabrielhilal , if you will delete the questio, you will not be able to get it back

Comment: @Lucifer - I will keep the question here... thanks