# What proportion of Peer-Pressure and Disciplined-badge-earning posts stay deleted?

Tags: discussion, badges, data-explorer, peer-pressure-badge, disciplined-badge

As far as I know, one can earn the [Peer Pressure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/36/peer-pressure) and [Disciplined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/35/disciplined) badges by deleting and subsequently undeleting posts with the appropriate scores (-3 and +3, respectively).  See: [I cheated on the Disciplined badge, how bad is it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95918/i-cheated-on-the-disciplined-badge-how-bad-is-it) and [Badges should reward positive behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107628/badges-should-reward-positive-behavior)

I guess most people don't care enough about these badges to actually use this kind of exploit, though.

**Question**: What proportion of Peer-Pressure and Disciplined-badge-earning posts stay deleted?

<s>Since it involves deleted posts, I don't think it's possible to whip up a Data Explorer query to answer this.  Perhaps there's another way to give an estimation.</s>  (My mistake.)

It seems totally possible to do this in Data Explorer, although my Data-Explorer-fu is not up to scratch.

Comment: Should be possible: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157462/can-some-metadata-about-deleted-posts-be-included-in-data-se ... so the ID is there and when the data explorer contains the posts granting the badge, then it should be possible

Comment: Well, might not be that easy, the explorer has a table for badges, but it doesn't contain a link to the post granting the badge.

Comment: I *guess* your *guess* is correct. The big quality problems on this network ... are really in different corners.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[I plead guilty ...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/279863/revisions)

Since Peer Pressure and Disciplined badges are awarded pretty soon after deletion, you can (if the posts are later undeleted) check the timestamps of the badge with the post history timestamps. [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1177346/disciplined-peer-pressure-badges-on-undeleted-posts?badgeName=Peer+Pressure) is a SEDE query where I only count the instances where the owner of the post deleted and undeleted it. They might have done so because they discovered a major flaw in their post and wanted to edit it in all rest, not necessarily to obtain the badge.

On Meta Stack Exchange, 99.46% of the Peer Pressure posts stay deleted, and 90.4% of the Disciplined posts. On Stack Overflow, it's 99.66% (for Peer Pressure) vs. 92.81% (Disciplined).

Comment: Those are about the ratios I would have expected.

Comment: Good point, I've done the delete-edit-undelete thing a few times when I wanted to stop downvotes until I fixed the problems I had found in my post. Typically this was with answers where I had misunderstood the question and needed a few minutes to formulate or reformulate an answer to the question actually asked. Of course, if I *couldn't* answer the actual question then I would leave my answer deleted.