# Badge for close-voting own question after someone close-voted it?

Tags: feature-request, badges, vote-to-close, badge-request

Would it be worth some honesty badge if one votes an own question for close? Possibly *after* someone else began voting, to prevend vandalizing this badge.

edit: I personally just missed the proper wording [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744324/decltype-and-mixing-adl-lookup-with-non-adl-lookup) and in the comments someone suggested a dupe that fits perfectly.

---

edit:

As per psubsee2003 in the comments, the badge shall be awarded *after* the question has been closed in order for it to be peer-reviewed. This accounts for preventing badge vandalism.

Proposed wording as per Gabriele Petronella:

> Contributed to close own question by casting a close vote.

Comment: Related: [Etiquette for closing your own questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5215/)

Comment: One of the few badge requests that isn't just off the wall, and actually makes sense.  I don't think enough users know you can vote to close your own post and this would help.  Only change I would suggest is the post has to be closed, rather than just getting 1 other close vote.

Answer (score 8):

Voting to close a question you asked shows a lot of self-discipline and it's a very positive and desirable behavior.

Some people understand why their question is receiving close votes, but I believe most of them don't even know they can vote to close it.

After all

> Badges exist to reward and encourage the kind of positive behavior we want in our community.

(source: [Purpose and use of badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97183/purpose-and-use-of-badges))

so I support this badge request as it looks appropriate. It would be along the same lines as the [`Peer Pressure`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure) badge.

However I propose the same change psubsee2003 exposed in the comments: the badge should be awarded when the post is actually closed, in order to provide a peer validation of the close vote itself.

It would read like

> Contributed to close own question by casting a close vote.

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 major criteria used for badges and all badges satisfy at least one of these:

- Badges should encourage positive behaviors
- Badges should teach users about the features of the site.

I think this proposed badge would actually satisfy both criteria.

First it encourages positive behavior by having users help clean up their own posts.  If a post isn't good, and a user recognizes it and they vote to close it they should be rewarded.

Second it teaches users about the features of the site.  At 250 rep, users get the [view close vote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) privilege, but with this privilege users also get the privilege to vote on their own posts (for closure) and I don't think many users are aware of this.  A badge here would help users learn that this functionality is available.  Which would help encourage the positive behavior.

As I mentioned in the [comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203988/badge-for-close-voting-own-question-after-someone-close-voted-it#comment650967_203988), I think the post needs to be closed first before awarding the badge to prevent gaming, or there needs to be some other controls to help someone from voting to close for no reason just to get the badge.

As for a name, I don't know if `Honesty` is an appropriate name as you aren't necessarily being honest for closing your own post.  `Cleanup` would work, but that is already a name for another badge, so maybe `Good Citizen` since someone who closes their own post is being a good citizen.

Comment: Isn't `Good Citizen` still too general? But then, I currently do not have a better proposal.

Comment: @phresnel many of the badge names are very general.  It is hard to be specific and keep the name short enough to fit on a badge.