# Badge suggestion: Well Behaved, for reading the Code of Conduct

Tags: feature-request, badges, code-of-conduct

One of the first badges most users usually get is the bronze Informed badge for reading the entire Tour page. This badge is designed to reward some basic reading about the site, and hopefully helping new users better understand how Stack Exchange works and what's expected of them.

Now that the Stack Exchange network has a [Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct), perhaps we should incentivize new users to visit it too? 
I propose a new bronze badge, Well Behaved, that will be granted to users reading through the Code of Conduct, in a similar way that Informed is granted for going through the Tour.

Comment: cross-site dupe: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372160/should-there-be-a-version-of-the-informed-badge-for-reading-the-code-of-conduc

Comment: [This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/372162/4916627) on the same feature-request on Meta Stackoverflow represents my opinion.

Comment: To read something doesn't mean you automatically agree with it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Badges Are Carrots

Badges, like dangling carrots, are an incentive.

An incentive is a thing that motivates or encourages someone to do something.

Bottom-line, we *should* be motivating or encouraging the reading of updated codes of conducts and badges fulfil this very function as does the announcement banner depicted in the following screen-shot:

[image: Announcement Banner]

Let's be less concerned with the meritocracy of badges and more concerned with the *function* of badges.

## Confirming Reading

Various tiers of (imperfect but no less sufficient) confirmations:

1. User hits code of conduct URL.
2. User scrolls to bottom of page.
3. User answers a singular random multiple choice question to demonstrate understanding.

Answer (score 9):

Most of what I was about to write is similar to Kendra's answer on [the MSO dupe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372160/should-there-be-a-version-of-the-informed-badge-for-reading-the-code-of-conduc) noted in the first comment:

> ...in my opinion, badges for reading something are kinda pointless.
>
> ...we *can't be sure* that you've read it...
>
> Honestly, I also find the "Informed" badge to be pointless, but there it is.

In addition to gameability, not everyone really needs to read the tour for each and every site to be able to be productive members; the same goes for the Code of Conduct.

In fact, since many people read docs like this only when they're linked to it after some issue, it could give mods/others some indication when and how they've been mod-messaged and how they responded, which is... kinda creepy.

Also worth noting that this would break the long-standing tradition of badges on a given site being exclusively for actions on that site. That is, reading the Code of Conduct would (presumably) get you the Well Behaved badge on every site you're a member of, whereas reading the tour for, say, CiviCRM SE gets you the Informed badge on just CiviCRM SE.

Comment: I didn't even _consider_ the fact that the Code is the same across network when I wrote my MSO answer, so indeed the badge across sites is a very good point. Glad you highlighted that.

Comment: But there could be a quiz...

Comment: @PeterMortensen I second quizzing the user by way of a singular random multiple choice question. Reiterated [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314793/260701).

Comment: Related: the old but still valid answers at [Purpose and use of badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97183/purpose-and-use-of-badges). Adding new functionality for a quiz (of any length) feels like the tail wagging the dog. Badges are supposed to be more like happy surprises for positive behavior than features or goals in and of themselves.

Answer (score 7):

I like the idea of this badge with one reservation, which is that I am not sure whether it is a good idea to give a user who reads the Code of Conduct, and later ignores it, a badge branding them "Well Behaved" for all time.

Since the Code of Conduct seems to have a large focus on being welcoming, I suggest that the badge you describe be implemented, but that it be named "Welcomed" instead:

- **Informed** for reading the Tour
- **Welcomed** for reading the Code of Conduct

We cannot force anyone to read either, but by offering these two easy badges, we are welcoming new users to each site that they land on, and letting them know what we think are two important steps to take before making their first post.

Comment: Wouldn't *Welcoming* be better? ...

Comment: After reading the Code of Conduct they should feel welcomed. Hopefully they will become welcoming to others.

Comment: Yes, but after reading the tour page, the user shall be informed and after reading the CoC welcoming.. (Oh and shouldn't users be welcomed in any case...?)