# Why have I not been awarded my badge yet?

Tags: support, badges

I recently achieved a flag weight of 500 over on StackOverflow.  I am curious as to why that has not resulted in my earning the Deputy badge.  I realize that the description of the badge states that you must "achieve a flag weight of 500 by reviewing and flagging appropriately", but a fair number of my flags have not come directly through the review interface.  I tend to spend most of my time browsing the site for questions I can answer, and flagging questions and answers that I happen across that I think should be flagged.  Is this my problem?  Do I need to have spent my time actually in the review interface?

Comment: "Is this my problem" heavens no. If only everyone went through old answers and questions to clean them up!! Your problem is simply time. Get a good night's sleep and the badge will be there in the morning(ish).

Comment: Congrats for your [deputy](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/1002/deputy?userid=702948) badge :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just wait a while. Some badges are awarded immediately, but others are not - an automated process generates them every so often.

So be patient, shouldn't take more than a day (in my experience).

From [How do "badges" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work):

> In some cases badges gained or lost may not show up immediately, but will instead be awarded the next time the system recalculates badges, *which occurs periodically*.

Comment: +1; I ran into the same problem last night and woke up to a shiny new badge (Electorate).