# Why I didn't received a Bronze Medal after reaching the goal "Curious"?

Tags: support, badges

I already have reached the goal, as it shows on the board of my profile:
[image]

It's been (at least) a week since I have reached the goal, but no medal counted.

In [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112871/why-have-i-not-been-awarded-my-badge-yet) question, it says that it takes probably a day for it.

Am I missing something regarding the proposed objective to get this medal?

Comment: The 'x' means you don't have a positive question record.

Comment: I see. But why SO counter let the score reach 5/5, if I haven't accomplished all the objectives?

Comment: Because there are two objectives and you've reached the first one which requires at least 5/5 but not the second.

Comment: Got it. Thank you, @RobertLongson. If you and Glorfindel want to post answers for the questions, feel free, and then I can upvote.

Comment: Your question is an exact duplicate, so you better click the button that is offered to you to mark it as such. That is much more efficient and convenient for future users, instead of having all kind of answers across multiple questions.

Comment: Agree. Thank you all.