# Which badges are stackable?

Tags: support, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do “badges” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work)

I've noticed only some badges can be earned multiple times whilst others cannot. For example I can get the 'Nice Answer' as many times as I like yet I can only earn the Mortarboard badge once.

Which badges are stackable? Is there or should there be a way of finding out by looking at the badges description?

Comment: In [How do "badges" work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work), you'll get the list of badges that can be awarded more than once.

Answer (score 5):

I'd guess it has to do with the presence of counted tags.  Nice Answer has its Good and Great answer levels, but no "10 posts with a score of 10" counterpart, while Mortarboard has the Epic and Legendary counterparts, "Earned 200 daily reputation 50/150 times."  So some badges have levels based on how high a threshold you reach, and others are based on how many times you reach a threshold, but it seems there are no progressions that have both.