# Why do some badges get awarded multiple times, while others are only awarded once?

Tags: support, badges

I noticed that some badges (such as *Nice Answer*: Answer score of 10 or more) are awarded each time the threshold is reached, but others (such as *Mortarboard*: Earned at least 200 reputation in a single day) are only awarded once.  Is there any particular reason for the two modes, or is it merely arbitrary?  (Maybe Mortarboard badges are awarded only once, because of the *Epic* badge? "Earned 200 daily reputation 50 times").

For consistency purposes, if the *Mortarboard* badge is awarded only once, perhaps its explanation should be changed to: "First time reaching 200 points in a single day," (which would mirror, say, *Supporter*: "First up vote").

To clarify, I'm not griping - I'm merely curious, as a trained software engineer.  At first, I thought maybe I had unearthed a bug; on second thought, I think it's simply a matter of an ambiguous explanation. I realize this is a trivial and inconsequential matter, but these are the kinds of things I sometimes notice and wonder about.

Comment: There would be a lot of people who would get the Mortarboard badge *every day*. Hitting the rep cap is not exactly hard especially on SO.

Comment: @Juhana it might not be as easy on English SE which this question was originally posted on's meta...

Comment: @davidsleeps: It is far easier to hit the rep cap on ELU than it is on SO. If you're not a past master on SO (and answering questions tagged with C#, Java, etc.), you're lucky to get one or two upvotes for each question you answer. Hell, I got the Unsung Hero badge on SO and Legendary on ELU. I hardly ever answer questions on SO these days.

Comment: @Juhana: The number of points needed to reach the cap is irrelevant.  If hitting 200 is too easy, it could be changed to 1,000 - and my question would remain the same.

Comment: You can't reach 1,000 rep per day. The rep cap is a hard limit, it's not there just for the badge. Changing the rep cap just because the badge is too easy to get would be crazy.

Comment: Whatever.  I only wondered why some badges were awarded multiple times, and others weren't.  Quibbling about details on individual badges doesn't help answer my question - although many of the links to the right were very helpful.

Comment: @Juhana Jon Skeet got [pretty close](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=1) yesterday, FWIW.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do "badges" work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work), [List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

Answer (score 6):

I think what you are really asking is why the description of each badge doesn't make it plain whether it is a one off or multiple, as I think the creation of each badge was just to provide a reward/motivation for a particular activity/behaviour.

Most of them are pretty explanatory, and as the wording won't really change the behaviour for either well-meaning community members or rep-whores I wouldn't imagine it will need to be changed.

Comment: Sort of.  I'm a newbie to the StackExchange forums - and was puzzled after I got one badge twice, and another only once.  The inconsistency intrigued me - that's all.  You're correct when you say my behavior or motivation won't be affected either way.  I visit to sharpen my mind; "_I don't need no stinkin' badges_".  Had I known about this meta-meta-forum, and seen all the questions I now see in the right-hand margin, I wouldn't have even bothered to ask.  Thanks - looks like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) answers my question.