# Duplicate badges when question is migrated back and forth

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, badges, migrated-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do “badges” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work)

Following the conversations on my question which was first moved to DSP, then moved back to SO, I noticed something strange, I don't think it's a wanted behavior over the StackExchange.

So I basically got some badges initially on SO based on the number of upvotes (which I would never have expected by the way). Fair enough.

When I was moved to DSP, I also got the badges for the number of upvotes on DSP.

But when I was moved back to SO, I still kept my badges on DSP, even if the message had been moved.

I won't complain since it's basically some free badges for me on DSP, but I wanted to know if that's really expected? When a question is moved back and forth, are you really supposed to keep all your badges in the "temporary" site where it was moved?

Comment: I don't think it's really a duplicate, I know how badges work, but it's just that I have received the same badge on both DSP and SO for the same question, even if now it is really on SO and not anymore on DSP.

Comment: All right then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Non-tag badges are not revoked under normal circumstances, so I'd say this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). In this case, you'll just not get another gold badge on DSP should you ever have another question with 100 upvotes. You can consider this one a bonus, I suppose.

[According to the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work), badges are only ever taken away on a case-by-case basis if the system was maliciously cheated to obtain them. You can hardly say that this was the case here.