# A user got gold badges more than listed in SO

Tags: discussion, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do “badges” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work)

The number of  [gold badges listed on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=general&filter=gold) are 13 but I have seen [a user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)  have 135 gold badges. Is it possible to have a specific gold badge more than once? Where did the additional gold badges came from?

Comment: You did click onto his [badges page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=badges&sort=class), did you?

Comment: He is not a user. He is the "Jon Skeet"!

Comment: Aren't tag badges adding to this total too?

Comment: @OzairKafray; I know - lol!

Comment: There are only [50 official Jelly Belly jelly beans flavors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jelly_belly#Official_50_flavors); but I could still have 65536 beans...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> is it possible to have a specific gold badge more than once?

yes, it is possible to award same badge multiple times
like this on [famous-question](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/28/famous-question)

> [image]

Also for: [great-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/25/great-answer) and [stellar-question](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/36/stellar-question)

You can see in this case the number of times the same badge has been awarded:

> [image]

(image taken from [Jon skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=badges))

Answer (score 6):

Yes - there are several badges that you can be awarded numerous times.

Some gold badges that can be awarded more than once are -

- [Famous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/28/famous-question) - Asked a question with 10,000 views.
- [Great Question](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/22/great-question) - Question score of 100 or more.
- [Great Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/25/great-answer) - Answer score of 100 or more.
- [Reversal](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/95/reversal) - Provided answer of +20 score to a question of -5 score.
- [Publicist](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/262/publicist) - Shared a link to a question that was visited by 1000 unique IP addresses.
- [Stellar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/36/stellar-question) - Question favorited by 100 users.
- [Populist](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/62/populist) - Highest scoring answer that outscored an accepted answer with score of more than 10 by more than 2x.

---

As shown in [the other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138865/172936) by [@Presley](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/176291/presleydias), on the [badges tab](https://stackoverflow.com/badges) there is  a short explanation of each badge and whether or not it can be awarded multiple times.

---

Here is a link to a post containing all the relevant information for all the tags on the network -

[List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)