# Why do some badges in the user profiles badges tab have a gray background?

Tags: support, badges

My java bronze badge has a light gray backgroudn (silver?) instead of a black one. Is it because it's a tag related badge? I couldn't find an explanation. Thanks!

[image: Gray badges?]

Comment: `Is it because it's a tag related badge?` Yes.

Comment: See [How do "badges" work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17853)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do "badges" work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grey background means it is a tag related badge.

Comment: Thanks! Also, [how do "badges" work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17853) from @MartijnPieters was very useful