# How do I know what my badges mean?

Tags: discussion, badges, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do “badges” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work)

I have recently joined stack overflow and have 3 badges. How have I been awarded these, and what do they mean?

Comment: Go to your profile and click on the badge. It takes to to a page that explains what the badge was awarded for

Comment: Just read the linked faq. :)

Comment: Welcome to [so]! :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see a list of badges and a brief explanation on the badges page - 
https://stackoverflow.com/badges

[image]

---

As [@chrisF](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140381/how-do-i-know-what-my-badges-mean#comment396144_140381) mentioned - you can also click on the badge to go to a page with users that have been awarded that badge and also a short description.

### [image]

For a more indepth explanation, you can check out this post - [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

Comment: +1 for the full descriptions link.