# What is the maximum number of times you can have a badge?

Tags: discussion, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do “badges” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work)

I'd realized that I've got a double badge. I thought you could have only one of each badge.

I'd like to know, what is the maximum number of times you can have a badge? Is it unlimited or is there a maximum quantity?

Can be the bronze badge be changed to a silver badge, and a silver badge changed to a gold badge?

Comment: Some badges can be awarded multiple times.

Comment: Badges are not upgraded, they accumulate. For example, suppose you get the bronze "Nice Question" badge for a question with score 10. If that question achieves a score of 25 later, you will get the silver "Good Question" badge in addition to your "Nice Question" badge.

Comment: From the linked faq: *Some badges can be earned more than once. If a user earns such a badge more than once, his name will appear on that badge's page once for each time he earned the badge. The badges listing on the user page will also display a multiplier next to the badge indicating the number of times it has been earned*

Comment: As for "Can be the bronze badge be changed to a silver badge, and a silver badge changed to a gold badge?" it is not covered in the faq and the answer is "No" - badge is permanent, you can earn silver badge in addition to bronze one, it's not "upgrading" the bronze.

Comment: @SLBarth then maybe this question will get the bronze "Bad Question"

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd ooops sorry i'm newbie on meta. but thank you.

Comment: @Josua no worry, we were all new. However only badge one can gain for downvoted posts is [Peer Pressure](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/36/peer-pressure) when deleting -3 or lower post - not relevant in your case since you can't delete your question now having an answer on it.

Comment: @JosuaMarcelChrisano: We'd never stop handing *those* out on SO... Badges are awarded to encourage positive behaviour, luckily!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most badges can only be awarded once, some can be awarded multiple times (and then there are no upper limits).

Badges that can be awarded multiple times will not 'upgrade' when you reach a certain count; e.g. just because [Jon Skeet has 1.4k Enlightened badges (and counting)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=badges&sort=recent) does not mean he gets to cash these in for gold ones.

See [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397) for the full details of each badge.

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if Jon got a couple more Enlightened badges while you were writing this...

Comment: His latest was for "Null reference exceptions in .net". Next one in 3... 2.... 1.....

Comment: Thank you. this answer enlightened me too :)