# max badges one can earn

Tags: discussion, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do “badges” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work)
>   [What is the maximum number of times you can have a badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143441/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-times-you-can-have-a-badge)

I was looking at badges page and I see there is a list of maximum 77 badges one can earn but looking at some famous stackoverflow users like Jon skeet, he has like around 3800 bronze badges and 157 gold badges how is this possible?

Correct me if I am wrong. I guess you cannot claim the same badge twice.

Comment: Apart from a not too low number of tag badges, many badges can be earned multiple times.

Comment: how can you earn it multiple times.. any examples you know of would be great

Comment: @lordlupine you'll want to check out Meta's [user-generated list of badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions).

Comment: Great link. was searching for already posted questions on this subject but didnt find this one. thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I see there is a list of maximum 77 badges one can earn

But there are also tag badges, which increases the amount of distinct badges considerably.

Apart from that, many badges (like Nice/Good/Great Answer/Question) can be earned multiple times.

Every time one of your answers/questions reaches a vote score of 10, you earn a [Nice Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/23/nice-answer) (resp- [Nice Question](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/20/nice-question)) badge. For every one of your questions that reaches 1000 views, you get a [Popular Question](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/26/popular-question) badge, etc.

If you look at [Jon Skeet's badges](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=badges), you'll see that he earned (at the time of writing) the [Enlightened](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/19/enlightened) badge 1558 times (and a fortiori, the [Nice Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/23/nice-answer) badge at least as often).

Comment: I understand that looking at the description of the badges one can figure out if it can be earned multiple times but just curious if there a way to see list of badges which can be earned multiple times or is it just trial and error. After all badges and reputation keeps you motivated to post answers.

Comment: I don't know of a list that only lists badges one can earn multiple times, and so the only way to know would be reading the description. But of course, there is a rule of thumb. If the badge is about one post, you can earn it multiple times. If it's about a general thing, a tag, a first whatever, it can only be earned once.

Comment: He's got the Nice Answer badge 3544 times.

Comment: Given that some badges can be earned multiple times, the literal answer to the question is "an infinite number", not 77.  Also, counting tags badges (and since there can be infinite tags) it's still an infinite number of badges (counting each instance once).

Comment: @Servy well, if you _really_ want to nitpick, the number of possible tags is finite, since tags can't be more than 25 characters long. The number is just incredibly large. (More than 6x10^35 even if you allow only lowercase English letters and hyphens.)

Comment: 3544 was almost an hour ago - now it's 3545 (and counting). :-)