# What are the Yellow badges for on the SO network? And can badges be removed once saved?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do “badges” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work)

On the badges page, some buttons have a yellow circle background:

```
Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total
```

[image]

Do you get negative points for these? What is the yellow for?

Also can badges be removed - example, I fill in all my profile and get a badge - can that then be revoked if I remove some of my profile fields once I get the badge (Autobiographer)

Comment: See also [How do "badges" work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work).

Comment: Ummm Bronze Medal, SIlver Medal and **GOLD** Medal?

Comment: -1 not enough jQuery.

Answer (score 9):

These are *Gold* badges, not yellow, and are considered the cream of the crop when it comes to badges.

See https://stackoverflow.com/badges

The other type of badge is for upvotes on answers taking Jon as an example:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=badges&sort=recent

You can see that he has loads of badges with a beige background. These are badges earned for his answers being up-voted. They are called tag badges (as they are earned per tag, not feat)

You can see the fill list here:

https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags

Answer (score 5):

These are [**Gold** badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=general&filter=gold).

[image]

Comment: Good looking hand drawn red circles! I approve.

Answer (score 3):

The gold badges are rare and hard to earn badges.

Taken from the legend under the badges tab:

> Gold Badges are rare. You’ll have to actively work toward these. They’re something of an accomplishment!

Answer (score 1):

As stated on the badges page [of Meta SO for example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges):

> Gold Badges are rare. You’ll have to actively work toward these. They’re something of an accomplishment!

Comment: Excellent - getting votes for just coping the description from the badges page!

Comment: @ChrisF: He even got the "Teacher" badge. :D