# A bug with badge counter?

Tags: bug, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do “badges” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work)

I noticed it today and wanted to report it. Know if its already been noticed or its something new

Someone (Don't know who :X) did serial upvotes on my past answers and I got +180 reputation and also did some good answers and total +250 reputation on a single day so I was awarded with a bronze badge "MortarBoard"

But the next day, i.e. Today the -180 was done because of serial upvotes but the badge still remains. 
Isnt there a provision to roll back such badges? or this is expected in the sense that I did earn more than 200 reputation a day but SO doesn't care if it was rolledback?

Comment: As it says in the faq under *What can cause a badge to be lost/revoked/taken away after it is awarded?* - *The Stack Exchange administration has stated repeatedly that "regular" badges never go away unless they were obtained by heinous cheating*. You did not cheat, thus you keep the badge.

Comment: okk.. Cool .. Thanks for your reply @ShaWizDowArd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design.

If you earn a badge and then the criteria change - e.g. you get a Nice Answer badge and then someone down-votes your answer, or as in your case the votes that sent you over the reputation cap were invalidated - you keep the badge.

The expectation is that you will earn that badge again at some point in the future (at which point you won't be awarded it again) so it's not worth removing it.

The only badges that can be removed are the tag badges.