# Got Autobiographer badge even without completing all fields

Tags: support, badges

I completed all fields and got Autobiographer but even after deleting some fields from my profile, I still have that badge. Why is that?

Comment: Badges don't get removed like that. You keep it once you have earned it. This is consistent across all similar badges.

Comment: I know the working But the fact is I have it without completing its criteria sorry :D

Comment: You said you *did* complete them, then later deleted.

Comment: And I quote: *"The Stack Exchange administration has stated repeatedly that "regular" badges never go away unless they were obtained by heinous cheating."* ... what you have done is not really heinous cheating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Badges are almost never removed once you get them.

A similar situation is when you get the Nice Answer badge by getting a score of 10, but then get downvoted again to a score of 9. The badge will be kept.

See **[How do "badges" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work)**