# Guru badge not awarded

Tags: support, badges, guru-badge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do “badges” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work)

I have been to Stack Overflow for last few months and earned around 1000 reputation. I Wonder why I am not earning silver badges.

> For GURU badge - Accepted answer and score of 40 or more

I have lot of such answers. And I wonder why I am not assigned with this badge. ( I noticed only about this and don't know if any more is missing )

Is it a bug?

Comment: Score is the number of upvotes minus downvotes. Not the amount of reputation you gained. Don't confuse those.

Comment: my mistake was the confusion between score and reputation. I thought both are same. Thanks

Comment: There would be some pretty serious badge-inflation if there was a silver badge for every accepted +4 answer.

Comment: @AnhSirkDasarp when you see a term you're not sure about, check [this glossary](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms) and on most cases you'll get clear answer. It already contains definition for score. :)

Comment: yeah.. got it. Thanks @ShaWizDowArd

Comment: By the way, your fastest way to get silver badge is just visit the site every day. After 30 such days in a row, [this badge](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/71/enthusiast) will be yours. :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd even faster would be to vote 40 questions a day; after 8 days one gets _Civil Duty_ with 300 votes

Comment: @gnat maybe faster, but also requires much more time and effort, assuming the votes are real and made after considerable thought. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd yeah.. but I have been visiting the site almost everyday. ( may have missed 1 -2 days in between ). :) Just noticed today that I didn't earn any silver yet :D

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I see - for the effort spent, just visiting 30 days in the row should be easier indeed. ["Reading and evaluation of posts to decide on what vote to cast takes time"](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/313/168 "quote source")

Comment: @AnhSirkDasarp "almost" is not enough.. you can see the "days in a row" in your profile, it should say something like "visited 587 days, **37 consecutive**" and clicking it will even open small calendar showing on which days exactly you visited.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Just now realized that I can view the days I visited. I could have earned enthusiast badge if I didn't miss one day between :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Description of [GURU](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/18/guru) badge

> **Accepted answer and score of 40 or more**. This badge can be awarded multiple times

[You do not have any accepted answer with score of 40 or more](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1441326/anhsirk-dasarp?tab=answers&sort=votes). So this badge is not awarded to you.

As [@Bart said here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154878/not-earning-silver-badges#comment444688_154878): Score means upvote minus downvote not reputation.

Comment: True, worth to explain that "score" means the net vote count (upvotes-downvotes) not the reputation earned from the answer.

Comment: Yeah , my mistake was the confusion between score and reputation. I thought both are same. Thanks

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Yup. As [Bart said](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154878/not-earning-silver-badges#comment444688_154878)

Answer (score 3):

You get that badge when you have **a single answer** with a score of 40 or more which was accepted by the asker. You don't have any answers that are near that score.