# Why doesn't undo-ing your 1st down vote take away Critic badge

Tags: support, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do “badges” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work)

I was awarded **Critic** badge on Stack OverFlow after I down voted a wrong answer. But then I noticed that it cost me 1 point so I undo that (which is not the righteous thing to do, I should have stuck to my vote). Why do I still have **Critic** badge?

Comment: Just a note that, on average, it doesn't cost you a full point to downvote. Many downvoted posts are deleted, and you'll get the point back.

Comment: :).. that's a good point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the behavior of all (non-tag) badges, not just that one badge.  Once you meet the condition(s) for the badge it is awarded and it will never be taken away (automatically), even if those conditions are no longer met.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Edited accordingly.

Comment: Unless you got the badge by fraud. IIRC, a couple of Publicist badges were removed because they were fraudulently obtained.

Comment: @DanielFischer Does that edit satisfy you?