# Can you lose a badge you've earned?

Tags: discussion, badges

I recently earned the Tenacious badge, but it occurred to me that some of these badges (like Tenacious and Unsung Hero) are based on a ratio of accepted answers.  So, if my ratio dips, will that cause me to lose a badge I earned?

Comment: @p.s.w.g Tag badges are revoked automatically if you don't meet the criteria for them anymore, and badges earned dishonestly can (and will) be revoked at any time.

Comment: Ordinary (non-tag) badges aren't revoked by the system, but you do have to earn a "makeup" badge, in some cases, before getting a new one.

Comment: It's always been my understanding that badges are never rescinded automatically, but in extenuating circumstances a moderator will rescind it. Not 100% sure though.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Can you provide an example? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @p.s.w.g: There's an example in the FAQ: [How do “badges” work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work?lq=1)