# Does somebody get the same badge twice or more?

Tags: discussion

How does people have hundreds of badges, when the list shows(When you click on Badges tab) few?

Answer (score 4):

Some badges can be awarded multiple times - for example the [Nice Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/20/nice-question) badge.

It will only show up once, but could be multiple awards.

See [How do badges work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work) for full details about the badge system.

Comment: I am surprised no one bothered to close this question when [the FAQ has it all](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bBEp4.png).

Comment: @Antony - duplicates serve a purpose, and having a specific question with a specific answer augments the [FAQ] tagged posts - no everyone will read through the long answer there ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can earn some badges more than once, such as the Nice Question/Answer, Good Q/A, Great Q/A, Populist ...