# Why have I earned the "supporter" badge without any activity?

Tags: support, badges

Today I have earned the "supporter" badge without any activity. But I don't know why earned this badge?

Comment: It looks like you've done 4 upvotes today and never voted before (pressed the up button)?

Comment: Why not just see the description of the badge? Also look at [How do “badges” work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17853/187824).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why have I earned the "supporter" badge without any activity?

See [the list of badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges):

[image]

This badge is earned when you vote up. You've voted up so you earn the badge.