# Removal of serial voting actions does not remove any badges awarded as a result of the upvoting

Tags: bug, badges, serial-voting

I was a victim of some serial upvoting, see the post, [The strange case of the waxing and waning reputation](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/572/the-strange-case-of-the-waxing-and-waning-reputation), on SE Raspberry Pi. Nothing particularly new or amazing in that, granted. However, during, and as a cause of, the serial upvoting, I was awarded the "Nice Question" bronze badge. The votes have, rightly, been removed by the system, but I still have the badge in my collection.

Here is a screen shot of my reputation changes, showing that the votes have been removed.

> [image: My reputation changes]

Here is a screenshot of the badge being awarded due to one of the serial upvotes.

> [image: Awarding of the Nice Question badge]

Here you can see that I still have the badge awarded.

[image: I still have the Nice Question badge]

Shouldn't I be stripped of the badge, in the same way that I was stripped of the reputation, if it was awarded as a by product of someone's thoughtless upvoting?

Comment: Also read: [What can cause a badge to be lost/revoked/taken away after it is awarded?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work)