# Received an "Enlightened badge" and then had my answer unaccepted

Tags: discussion, bug

Per the subject, I'm wondering if my enlightened badge will disappear (it hasn't yet, but my answer was only recently unaccepted). To be clear, I'm not worried about my badge or my answer being unaccepted (a different answer was accepted in my place that absolutely deserved it). I'm mainly just curious about how thorough Stack Exchange is with edge cases. In detail:

1. I posted this answer: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/190799/149676
2. The answer was accepted pretty quickly.
3. After it was accepted another answer was posted that answered the question even better
4. A day later I received the enlightened badge
5. A couple of hours later the other answer was accepted in my place.

I already had a couple of enlightened badges, and if I click on the badge to see the list of answers that I received it for I see this answer.  Clicking on that answer from the enlightened badge page brings me to my non-accepted answer. This begs the question: Will Stack Exchange remove the badge from my profile? I feel like it should.

Comment: This is already answered in the FAQ: [How do "badges" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work) ("*In most cases, regular badges, once earned, are yours to keep.*")