# Can the number of earned badges be decreasing?

Tags: support, badges

Nowadays, I do not visit my Stack Exchange site frequently. Until now, I know that if I obtained some **badge** once, then it is permanent. This is one difference from **reputation**. Today, I suspect that my number of badges decreased. My question is: **Can we lose our badges?**

Comment: Hello :) Do you have any idea of the kinds of badges you may be missing? The [post on how badges work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17853/369802) has a section on what can cause you to lose badges, and what kinds of badges you can lose. These are essentially only tag badges, only under exceptional (and clearly abusive) circumstances would you lose any other badges.

Comment: In fact I have no silver-tag badge but I suspect that my one silver badge may be lost. This suspect is depending on my memory (so that in fact any badge may not be lost). When I lost some badge, I can know ?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can see when you lose a badge, I've asked that in chat. Hopefully someone notices and can answer that for you. But it does seem plausible you may have lost your silver tag badge, as tag badges can be lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's possible, but in practice only for one class of badges: [tag badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68395/295232). Each night your tag scores are recalculated; if you fail to meet the criteria (because of downvotes or retaggings) you'll lose the badge.

> Unlike most other badges, tag badges are revoked immediately if you ever cease to meet their criteria, which can happen if your answers are downvoted, deleted, or converted to community wiki, if the tag is removed from questions that you've answered, or if the tag becomes ineligible for badges because it's no longer used on 100+ questions.

Normal badges can't be lost, except for egregious cases of vote fraud when the Community Team may decide to manually revoke unfairly earned badges.