# Why are some badges from the "Select your next badge" window not listed on the list of badges pointed on the tour page?

Tags: bug, badges, tag-badges

Why does the description of the list of badges on the tour of a SE site does not match the content of the "Select your next badge" information window shown to the user when they receive a new badge?

#### Context

For instance, on the activity page of the https://psychology.stackexchange.com, clicking on "Track the next one" yields an information box "Select your next Badge" with a list of badges:

[image: Select your next Badge gizmo on Psychology SE]

But the [list of badges](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/help/badges) pointed at by the [tour page](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/tour) ("See all badges") of Psychology SE does not list some of those badges (such as "cognitive-psychology"):

[image: list of Bronze badges on Psychology SE]

Comment: I don't see list of badges in the Tour page, so I don't know what you are asking or reporting here. Please clarify, and post screenshot of the list you mention.

Comment: Also, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjKz7.png) is Gizmo, I don't understand how it's related to the question, please use the actual English word. If you mean it as gadget, it's slang and informal, avoid using slang in posts here.

Comment: The badges in your screenshot are (bronze) "tag badges". They are described in the Help Center page that you linked in your question, under Tag Badges, in between Participation Badges and Moderation Badges (at around 2/3rd of the page).

Comment: Note that there is another "select your next badge" window for regular badges, available from the second block in the Summary on your profile.

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard: I added a screenshot of the list of bronze badges. I used the term "Gizmo" according to the definition "A nonsensical placeholder name for something that one does not know the proper term for" from https://www.wordnik.com/words/gizmo, I did not think it was Slang (and apologize if it is) but nevertheless replaced it with a more descriptive term.

Comment: I see now, it has nothing to do with the tour page, that's what confused me, it's just matter of asking what is the meaning of tag badges. As for gizmo it is slang, as clearly written in [a better dictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gizmo), which clearly adds `(slang)` before the definition. It's good that people try to build a free dictionary, but it appears to fail in basic stuff and better not rely on it.

Comment: @Marijn: oh! I kind of understand now that  "cognitive-psychology" is a "tag badge", but I do not understand the criteria for "awarding" it, "You must have a total score of 100 in at least 20 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge", especially since the definition does not mention the tag itself?

Comment: Anyway, what you look for is [this faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for), see under "Tag Badges".

Comment: Here's the FAQ which covers badges, including tag badges: [How do "badges" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work)

Comment: Voting to reopen, the edit clarify what the question is about.

Answer (score 4):

The badge "cognitive-psychology" is a "Tag Badge", such as [described](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for/68395#68395) as follows in an answer to the Meta SE question "How do Badges work?":

> Users may earn badges on any site for positive contributions to established tags used on that site. Each tag badge has the same name as the tag for which it was awarded.

I still think that this should be explained better in the tour page than by the simple sentence "*You must have a total score of 100 in at least 20 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge*" on the [badge tour page](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/help/badges) of the main, non meta, website, but the [Meta SE question about badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work) has a clearer an more complete [description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for/68395#68395).