# Does the peer pressure badge get awarded more than once?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, peer-pressure-badge

I deleted an old answer that had a -3 score, and didn't get a peer pressure badge.

If it's not intended to be awarded more than once, it loses its reason to be, that is encouraging people to delete (what the community considers) bad posts.

Should it be awarded more than once or not? If it is, could it become like the [troll cap](http://37signals.com/svn/archives2/introducing_the_troll_cap.php)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's awarded just once. I'm tempted to say it should be awarded for each -3 post you delete, but I'm not so sure that's something we want to celebrate more often.

Comment: The thing is, the post exists, if the purpose is to encourage its deletion, it should

Answer (score 10):

[It's not awarded more than once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10026/which-badges-are-awarded-only-once).  It's also one of those badges that aren't awarded instantly, but rather seem to be awarded on a batch basis some minutes to hours later.

I don't really see the value in awarding this one more than once -- it corresponds more to a particular behaviour that you have done, rather than corresponding to a particular question or answer (as the multiply-awarded badges do).

Answer (score 4):

This would encourage some users to try and rack up the most Peer Pressure badges on the site. No thanks.

Comment: Seems reasonable, but on the other hand, I haven't seen a flood of people trying to earn even a first Disciplined badge.

Comment: Well, that is part of my question/discussion

Comment: Most people don't notice the badges.

Comment: Most people don't post questions that read "PENIS PENIS PENIS" either, yet decisions get made in the site setup to prevent it.