# Can you receive the Fanatic Badge more than once?

Tags: discussion, consecutive-days, activity-badges

Just curious if after receiving the Fanatic badge, and you start another streak of consecutive days, do you get another Fanatic badge?

Edit: I guess a more general question, which badges can you receive more than once?

Comment: possible duplicate of [List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

Comment: Related (if not duplicate): [Which badges are awarded only once?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10026/which-badges-are-awarded-only-once)

Comment: It would be cool if the Badges were wikis too, so we could put the information from the 'List of all badges with full description' details on each badges page.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nope, it's a "one-off" badge; it's only awarded once.

Comment: @Jon - Is there a list (maybe in the faq) that contains the 'one-off' badges?

Comment: @SwDev yes, at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions ; I've voted to close this question as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @SwDev, most badges that can be rewarded more than once say so.  If it doesn't say so, assume it's a 1 time only badge.

Comment: @Popular, just because a question contains the answer to a different question doesn't mean they are duplicates.  I disagree that this is a duplicate.

Comment: @jjn Hm, I thought they changed the policy a few months ago to explicitly allow closing "subset questions" as dupes. I'll see if I can find the post that made me think that.

Comment: Found it: ["if a user asks, 'What does the IP address 128.0.1.1/24 mean?' it’s OK to close that as a duplicate of a more general question like 'What do IP addresses of the form a.b.c.d/e mean?'"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/)

Answer (score 5):

No, that I can tell you. 272 consecutive days and counting :)

Comment: Confirmed. 644 (consecutive) days, here. And counting.

Comment: 101 cousecutive days and counting..