# How visited is visited in the context of Fanatic?

Tags: support, badges, activity-badges

The fanatic badge is awarded if you visited the site for 100 consecutive days. Apart from [needing serious help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58404/please-add-an-%C3%9Cber-fanatic-badge), but I was wondering, what does a visit entail? Any of these?

- Visit for at least 1 second
- Visit for at least 86.400 seconds
- Visit and did something, incl. voting, tagging, commenting, time of visit not counted
- Visit and did some more thing, at least asked/answered/edited a question
- Visit site while John Skeet is present

In short, is a visit a hit, or an active visit?

Answer (score 5):

As per the [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67402/254554)

> #### Fanatic
>
> - gold; awarded once
> - Visit the site for 100 days in a row
>
>   - This can be tracked in the user profile under "consecutive days"
>   - Simply loading the site is **not** enough to count as a "visit"
>
>     - The exact amount of activity required to count as a visit is not public information
>   - Each "day" lasts from midnight UTC to immediately before midnight, UTC; days are **not** counted in local time

As per SO moderator 'ChrisF' [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298532/3317140):

> You need to do more than just load the home page to register as a
>   "visit" for the badge. This may include viewing question pages, your
>   profile etc. It's not guaranteed to be just one of these other pages
>   either. The exact criteria aren't public though, so even if I knew I
>   couldn't tell you.

As per Server Fault moderator 'voretaq7' [comment](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3108/mechanics-of-fanatic-badge#comment5812_3109):

> Generally voting on a few questions and/or asking/answering/commenting
>   should guarantee you credit for a "visit" -- basically legitimately
>   use the site and you'll almost certainly get credit for the day :)

As per Founder Jeff Atwood's response to a user who asked about [Consecutive days problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97/66485#66485) (Thanks CRABOLO for the link)

> We see a login on 10-2 but no access to internal pages (login pages,
>   along with a number of other homepage style pages, don't count as
>   "access").

Comment: Ah, I somehow didn't find that list of all badges, my bad. I just queried Meta and the description on my user page... Thanks. Besides, I didn't know that Area 51 badges means badges on any site. Put in other words: I thought that different sites maintained different badges?

Comment: Different sites do maintain different badges, but as sites move from area51 to beta then to graduation, you can earn badges on A51 that are associated with your activity helping a particular proposal become a site.

Comment: Hmm... are [these](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66485/244519) the actual requirements... leaked by the founder 5 years ago?  So probably viewing any actual question is enough. But why not do at least 1 edit or review to have public proof you were there!

Comment: @CRABOLO Excellent find... added to answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Abel [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156645/254554) is also an excellent read.

Comment: Thanks for the additions and explanations!