# Symbol variation, to mark badges which can be earned more than once

Tags: feature-request, badges, icons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mark which badges are capable of being won > 1 time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7424/mark-which-badges-are-capable-of-being-won-1-time)

Different Symbols could carry the information, that a badge can be earned multiple times: [image]

(If you have a deja-vu: This question was an answer, which wasn't a real answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10026/156431)).

animuson claims, that many badges are decorated with a text, which says "First ...", which indicates, you can earn it only once. That's right. But a lot of the badges don't indicate anything in the text:

[image: badges-2]

And in some views, this information isn't visible - you have to hover over every badge, to see the tooltiptext, which won't always tell you, whether it is possible to receive the badge multiple times:

[image: badges-1]

(Except you earned a badge already multiple times, of course).

Of course it would be some work, to change those badges, but apart from that, I don't see any drawback from this feature.

Comment: Why should a push-pin icon convey that a badge can be earned more than once?

Comment: I think that's intended to be two gold discs, not a push-pin, @CodyGray.

Comment: @PopularDemand: That's right. It was harder to do than expected, and I would suggest to make it a bit better. My graphic capabilities are somewhat limited.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of my question.  As the poster says, it's an expansion of an answer, which is a common way feature requests come about.

Comment: Yes, let's not close this. While the other question is older, this one presents what is a pretty decent solution. Instead of a close vote, put a bounty on it. :)

Answer (score 3):

No. **This is completely unnecessary.** We already have plenty of information in the badges FAQ here on meta if anyone is confused. A majority of the badges that can only be awarded once are already marked with the word "First" at the beginning of their descriptions, which is a big enough indicator that you can't earn it multiple times. Also, you can click through to the badge's page to see if it is awarded multiple times.

[image: This badge can be awarded multiple times.]

---

You haven't established a valid reason *why* this information is needed. You say "why not?" I say "who cares?" What benefit does this change serve to the quality of the network? Honestly, most of the badge definitions are pretty straightforward in figuring out which ones are awarded multiple times and which are not.

- **First retag**
  Obviously, you can retag things many times, but the keyword first makes this a one-time deal.
- **Answer score of 25 or more**
  You can have multiple answers, and multiple answers with a score of 25 or more. So logically, you can receive this badge multiple times.
- **Raised 500 helpful flags**
  You only have *one* helpful flag count, which continues incrementing with each helpful flag. So logically, once you hit the 500 mark, you get the badge and you're done.

Are there any descriptions that are confusing to you that you can't logically determine whether they're awarded once or multiple times?

As for viewing badges in a user's activity; again I come to the question of why does it matter? What use is that information when you're viewing *someone else's* profile? Why do I need to know that a badge *they've* earned can be awarded multiple times?

Comment: "A majority" means, that from the absence of the word "first", you can't conclude it is awareded multiple times, and it isn't overviewfriendly. You have to have that in mind, to scan a whole page of badges and don't see it without hovering over tooltiptexts, when looking at the users badges for example. I updated my question to make it more obvious.

Comment: What do you possibly have to gain from seeing this information? Nothing. You shouldn't be focused on which badges you can earn more than once. You should be focused on contributing to the site. Seeing at a glance that you can earn this badge again is completely useless. If you're *really* that curious, click the badge and read the description. It's that simple.

Comment: That is an invalid argument. If we shall not be interested in badges, hide them or go a step further and abandon them completely.

Comment: Badges are there to encourage good behavior. Like a "hey that was good, here's a badge for it." You shouldn't be *hunting* for badges, because it only leads to misuse of the system. Most often seen with editing badges where people make crap edits just to get their count up for the badges.

Comment: I don't know how you know, that people make crap edits for getting a badge - isn't that speculation? I reviewed some edits and didn't find much crap, which I would associate with badge hunting. And the whole idea is not about badge hunting, but for an easy overview.

Comment: There are plenty of examples and even people flat-out admitting to it here on Meta.

Comment: OK. So we have different experiences.

Comment: The Enlightened description on the badge page says "first", but it can be awarded multiple times.

Comment: @LanceRoberts: Yes, but it's used in a completely different context. It's very obvious it's not talking about your first time doing something.

Comment: If it's wrong to be incentivized by the badge, but the Team has explicitly stated (as you seem to agree from the word "encourage") that badges are to be an incentive for good behavior, then aren't they in the wrong for creating an incentive that encourages the bad behavior of pursuing badges?

Comment: Who said it's wrong to be incentivized? I've said it's wrong to hunt for badges. They should come from natural use of the site's features. But that's not really relevant to adding silly icons. It involves adding them to the sprite, adding more CSS to account for them and apply them to the badges, and all so people can tell they can be earned multiple times. Like I've said, they're completely obvious whether or not you can earn them multiple times just from reading the description. I don't mind your feature of adding "(once)" or something small to the end, but this feature is just over-the-top.